# ASP Net Core - не получается достучаться к эндпоинту

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fileupload

написал html форму чтобы закидывать данные

```
<form action="/bookmarks/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>
        Text file:
        <input type="file" name="textFile"><br>
    </label>
    <label>
        Image file:
        <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/jpeg"><br>
    </label>
    <label>
        Bookmark path:
        <input type="text" name="bookmarkPath">
    </label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"/>
</form>
```

и метод контроллера который должен принять два файла и строку

```
[HttpPost("new")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertBookmark(IFormFile textFile, IFormFile imageFile, [FromBody]string bookmarkPath)
```

не понимаю что не выходит, выдает ошибку `415 Unsupported Media Type`
как это переделать чтобы можно было пересылать два файла и строку?

Comment: Используйте `[FromForm]` вместо `[FromBody]`

Comment: @Ares точно, теперь работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Перенесу ответ из комментария:*

Вам нужно использовать `[FromForm]` вместо `[FromBody]`, так как `bookmarkPath` отправляется как `multipart/form-data`.